# Core Data using NSArray does not preserve any data after program termination

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsarray, transformer-model

I'm attempting to configure the transformer to preserve array objects. It was successful to create new data after refreshing data, however when I killed the program and then reopened it, the data was gone. What did I overlook?

Here my startup code:

```
func createDatabase() {
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(UUIDTransformer(), forName: NSValueTransformerName("UUIDTransformer"))
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(TheCategoriesTransformer(), forName: NSValueTransformerName("TheCategoriesTransformer"))
    
    do { theDailyData = try contextDataCore.fetch(The_daily_data.fetchRequest()) } catch { }
    do { theHabitList = try contextDataCore.fetch(The_habit_list.fetchRequest()) } catch { }
    do { thePhotoData = try contextDataCore.fetch(The_photos.fetchRequest()) } catch { }
}
```

Here my transformer code:

```
class UUIDTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let uuid = value as? [UUID] else { return nil }

        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: uuid, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            return data
        } catch {
            return nil
        }

    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }

        do {
            let uuid = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: data) as! [UUID]
            return uuid
        } catch {
            return nil
        }

    }
}

class TheCategoriesTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let uuid = value as? [String] else { return nil }

        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: uuid, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            return data
        } catch {
            return nil
        }

    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }

        do {
            let categories = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: data) as! [String]
            return categories
        } catch {
            return nil
        }

    }
}
```

Create new data:

```
func newJournalData(theDate: Date, theHabitID: UUID? = nil, theSubject: String? = nil, theJournal: String? = nil, theMind: String? = nil, theWeather: String = "NA") {
    let repairDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: theDate)
    let freshDate = Calendar.current.date(from: repairDate)
    
    var newHabitID: [UUID] = []
    if theHabitID != nil { newHabitID.append(theHabitID!) }
    
    var theImpactCount = 0
    var theImpactTotal = 0
    
    let findHabitImpact = theHabitList.first(where: { $0.theID == theHabitID })
    
    for countX in theHabitList {
        switch countX.impact {
        case 0: theImpactTotal += 1
        case 1: theImpactTotal += 5
        case 2: theImpactTotal += 10
        default: theImpactTotal += 0
        }
    }
    
    if findHabitImpact != nil {
        switch findHabitImpact?.impact {
        case 0: theImpactCount += 1
        case 1: theImpactCount += 5
        case 2: theImpactCount += 10
        default: theImpactCount += 0
        }
    }
    
    let finalImpact = Int((Double(theImpactCount) / Double(theImpactTotal)) * 100)
    
    let newJournalData = The_daily_data(context: contextDataCore)
    newJournalData.date = freshDate
    newJournalData.habitData = newHabitID
    newJournalData.theSubject = theSubject
    newJournalData.journal = theJournal
    newJournalData.yourMind = theMind
    newJournalData.theWeather = theWeather
    newJournalData.percent = Int16(finalImpact)
    
    do { try contextDataCore.save(); createDatabase() } catch { print("Error") }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]   [image]

I can see the array from habitData without any problems when I create the data. When the program is closed and reopened, just the habitData data is lost; all other data remains intact. After restarting the program, habitData always returns nil.

Comment: Have you verified that your transformers are not returning `nil`?

Comment: I done it a few times...refresh data (tableview) shows data, however when I quit the app, open it again, the data is gone. Date, theSubject, journal, and so on are all good, but habitData is gone.

Comment: As it turned out, the category array was great, but why couldn't habit data work? It now works if I change the [UUID] to a [String]. Why did string work instead of UUID?